# Schengen C multiple-entry visa by Poland

Tags: visas, schengen, poland

I have a multiple l-entry Schengen C visa obtained on the basis of my sponsor friend in Poland. When I applied for a visa Isubmitted an itinerary for 29 September to 8 October, and the embassy granted me a 70-daysm multiple-entry visa, even though I asked for only 9 days. So my questions are:

1. Can I change the date of my flight as I am getting a cheaper fare if I travel 4 days after my intended travel?
2. Can I do another trip say in November on this same visa, or I will have to show some other proof at the border upon entry?
3. Can I go to Germany for a few days from Poland if I want without any checks?

Just to be clear I want to have a good record for my future Schengen visa applications. I don't want to break any rules whatsoever.

Comment: Be careful: you must pay attention to both the dates of validity and the "duration of stay."  Is the duration of stay listed as 70 days?

Comment: to be exact the duration of stay is 69 days. ANd its valid from 23 sept to 30 nov 2017. so from what i understand is that i can stay for 69 days between these validity dates. correct?

Comment: There is a field on the visa called "duration of stay" which should have a value between 1 and 90.  Does it say **69** there?

Comment: yes it says 69 days

Answer (score 1):

A Schengen visa has both validity and duration of stay. You can stay as many days as the duration of your visa, within the time window of the validity.

- If someobdy had a validity of April 1st to April 28 and 7 days duration, he could stay April 1st to April 7th, or April 2nd to April 8th, ..., or April 22nd to April 28th.
- The first day counts as a day and your last day counts as a day.
- You cannot stay more than 90 days out of the preceding 180 days on **any short-stay visa or combination of short-stay visas.**

Question 1: Yes. You can shift the dates within your validity perior.

Question 2: Depends on how much duration you have used up.

Question 3: Yes, as long as Poland remains your main destination. There could be problems if somebody thinks that you wanted to go to Germany all along, and left that out of your visa application. But *minor* changes to the itinerary are OK.

Comment: my duration of stay is 69 days. visa is valid from 23 sep to 30 nov 2017. 
yes i want to go to poland first as per my visa as it is my main destination and then visit germany for maybe 3 or 4 days. same for my second trip.

Comment: Please see: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/reminder-95-of-all-schengen-questions-have-already-been-answered